# How do I merge multiple excel xlsm files, with multiple worksheets in one Dataset?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to merge 3 different xlsm files into one. The 3 files have one tab with the same name "SUmmary" and this is the sheet i want to mert in one dataframe, but when creating the dataframe I get an error that i haven't being able to fix

What i have tried:

```
<for f in files_xlsm:
data= pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Summary')
df = df.append(data)>
```

The error:

```
<IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-fcda0775e736> in <module>()
  1 #Loop over files to append to empty dataframe
  2 for f in files_xlsm:
----> 3     data= pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Summary')
  4     df = df.append(data)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FIM 2.0 IP Review FP Baby - Copy.xlsm'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do the the job as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Summary') for f in glob.glob('path/*.xlsx')],  ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to load your files each as a dataframe then use pandas concat

```
import pandas as pd
for f in files_xlsm:
    if files_xlsm.index(f) == 0:
        df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Summary')
    else:
        merge_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Summary')
        df = pd.concat([df, merge_df])
```

but your stack trace shows that your error is actually that your script can't find the file 'FIM 2.0 IP Review FP Baby - Copy.xlsm' so make sure you are running this script in the same directory that you have that saved in.